# MySQL timediff between two timestamps on the same column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in my MySQL Database that is called "history" and is a collection of the historic movements of a file (sort of a Log) as follows:

```
| file_id | origin | destination |         date        | user |
|   1     |   2    |      3      | 2017-06-11 23:46:00 |  1   |
|   1     |   1    |      2      | 2017-06-11 17:32:00 |  1   |
```

Origin and destination columns are foreign keys of places stored in the table 'places'. So, for instance, the time the file 1 was at a the place number 2 should be equal to:

**Time of arrival** AKA *date* in whichever row has the file_id=1 and the destination=2

**Minus**

**Time of departure** AKA *date* in whichever row has the file_id=1 and the origin=2

I tried to do the following SQL query through phpMyAdmin to test:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF
(HOUR,
(SELECT date FROM `historia` WHERE `file_id`='1' AND `destination`='1'),
(SELECT date FROM `historia` WHERE `file_id`='1' AND `origin`='1'))
```

However this is giving a "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error message.

What is the correct way to Query the time difference between those two rows?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it helped you to achieve what you were looking for. This way, it won't be lost in thread and would help others who have similar issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following statement (the statement is followed by its result-set):

```
select timediff(h1.date,h2.date) from historia h1 join historia h2 where h1.file_id = h2.file_id and h1.origin = h2.destination;
+---------------------------+
| timediff(d1.date,d2.date) |
+---------------------------+
| 06:14:00                  |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```